# How to retrieve field information "PermissionSet.applicationVisibilities"?

Tags: api, permissions, metadata

"PermissionSet" has several fields like "applicationVisibilities" or "fieldPermissions" like described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm).

How to get all fields (including name and/or if its required) via API?

Answer (score 1):

when you execute the retrieve command from a package this would help you

sfdx force:source:retrieve -x path/to/package.xml

package.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>replace this with your permission set api name</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <version>50.0</version>
</Package>
```

then review the permissionSet file retrieved, should contain all you described.